# Create fixed size array on stack

Tags: c#, arrays, stack

I need a fixed data structure that (for performance reasons) is managed on the stack, but behaves like an array

I am aware that I can create something like this:

```
using System;

namespace X
{
    public sealed struct CustomArray<T>
    {
        private const Int32 n = 2;

        private T _field_1;
        private T _field_2;
        // ...
        private T _field_n;

        public T this[Int32 idx]
        {
            get
            {
                switch(idx)
                {
                    case (0): return _field_1;
                    case (1): return _field_2;
                    // ...
                    case (n): return _field_n;

                    default: throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
                }
            }
            set
            {
                switch(idx)
                {
                    case (0): _field_1 = value; break;
                    case (1): _field_2 = value; break;
                    // ...
                    case (n): _field_n = value; break;

                    default: throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this is not really handy for structures consisting of ~50 elements. is there a way to achieve this in a more convenient and maintainable way?

thanks ahead

Comment: Are you sure heap-allocated array will hinder performance of your application? If your `struct` has a short life-time and there will be no more roots to your array, GC, even if it happens during the performance-critical section of your program, will be very fast.

Comment: I have hundreds of thousands of objects managed on the heap, so I try to avoid insert/ delete operations on the heap as many as possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can allocate an array in stack using [stackalloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4.aspx) keyword, seems like it will satisfy your stack allocation needs. Unfortunately it requires you to be in unsafe context.

```
int* block = stackalloc int[100];
```

Comment: great. will wrap this into a struct. great help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to declare the datastructure with named fields as a struct, and create it on the stack (like a local variable).  If you need array like access to the data in the stack you can do something like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=16, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct DataStructure
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]public fixed ushort[8];

    [FieldOffset(0)]public ushort wYear; 
    [FieldOffset(2)]public ushort wMonth;
    [FieldOffset(4)]public ushort wDayOfWeek; 
    [FieldOffset(6)]public ushort wDay; 
    [FieldOffset(8)]public ushort wHour; 
    [FieldOffset(10)]public ushort wMinute; 
    [FieldOffset(12)]public ushort wSecond; 
    [FieldOffset(14)]public ushort wMilliseconds; 
}
```

Then you can reference it like this:

```
private static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataStructure ds;

    ds.wYear = 2015;
    ds.wMonth = 04;

    ds.array[0] = 2014;
    ds.array[1] = 05;
}
```